# force programs and connections to use a proxy server in windows?

Tags: windows, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global proxy settings for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/29701/global-proxy-settings-for-windows)

I am based in the uk currently, but have a deep craving for american-only websites. So naturally i have a (paid) proxy server - and while i'd like to know of other paid servers out there, that isn't this question.

This question is - when i visit amazon.com, it knows i am not in the us, but in the uk. Same browser (firefox), usig the proxy server. So:

1. How is amazin doing this?

And the main question(WINDOWS question)

2. I currently use a trial version of the "proxifier" to get around this. Is there another way of forcing all connections to use some given proxy? Is it a windows setting? I have two firewalls (eset and windows firewall), can either of them do this? Is there another program that can do this instead?

Proxifier seems to do a whole passle of things, and i really only need to make all connections use a given proxy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [a VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) for what you want. It'll give you a US based server, with a US IP, which will let you use *every* US-only service. (Except if they are explicitly banned every VPN IP.) Also: This will tunnel *everything* on your computer. Not just Firefox.

For providers, just type: VPN providers, into Google. I don't want to promote anyone.