# Windows Store says my PC isn't connected to the internet

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I have been using Windows 8 for the past few days but suddenly since a couple of days I'm not able to use my Windows Store.

Every time I try to open it, it says that my system has to be connected to internet to use the store even though my computer is connected to the internet and it is working too.

This is the message that is shown when I open my app store:

> Your PC isn't connected to the internet. To use the store connect to internet and try again

Comment: have you tried to disable your firewall?

Comment: Do you have a proxy? You might need to set the machine proxy. See the `netsh` commands [here](http://superuser.com/a/375525/23461).

Comment: Related: https://windowsreport.com/pc-not-connected-internet/#1

Answer (score 2):

Running

> **WSReset.exe**

worked for me.

Simply go to bottom left corner and right click.

Select search and type **WSReset**, the app will show up on the left.

Click this to run it and my store began working again.

Comment: wsreset just hangs for me. The CLI window just stays open forever.

Answer (score 2):

#### I've had this problem a few times, and I found two solutions that always worked for me.

- Download and run these two *Diagnostics Troubleshooting Wizards*: [`apps.diagcab`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/apps.diagcab) and [`microsoftaccounts.diagcab`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/microsoftaccounts.diagcab) *<sup>(via [askvg.com](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-store-metro-apps-and-microsoft-account-related-problems-in-windows-8/))</sup>* (both are safe downloads from microsoft).
- Run `WSReset.exe` -|- press <kbd>Windows logo</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or swipe in from bottom-right corner and tap/click "Search"),
  search for wsreset, right-click or press and hold on "wsreset", and select "Run as
  Administrator".

You should also check if the system time is correct. A lot of websites have trouble connecting if this isn't set to the right time. The best thing would be to set it to automatically synchronize with a time server, if this isn't already the case.

1. Go to the "PC Settings" app
2. "Time and language" --> "Date and time"
3. Make sure "Set time automatically" is set to "On"
4. Set the correct time zone and make sure "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" is set to "On".

Comment: The microsoftaccounts.diagcab download was removed by Microsoft, can you upload it somewhere? Such file is nowhere to be found, every single post links to the dead URL. Thanks

Comment: I also did not find `apps.diagcab` but `AppsDiagnostic.diagcab`. And it did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My system did this.

Windows update has installed a new driver for you, how helpful!

Do the following to resolve. I find rolling back the drivers in Windows 8 doesn't work, so here we will un install the device, remove the software, and then reboot windows. it will find the device, install it's own drivers, and work fine... until it updates again.

Go to DESKTOP (not metro)
Right click in the bottom right hand corner (invisible start button)
Select DEVICE MANAGER
Look for Network Adapters, and expand this.
Double click your wireless card name
Choose the Driver Tab
Click Uninstall at the bottom
if prompted, say yes you want to remove the software as well

re-boot system and it will work.

you may want to 'hide' this update from your system. post back for directions if you need them.

Comment: Any idea why the new driver would *only* disable Store access and not all internet access?

Comment: I solve this problem by disable and then enable wifi adapter. Maybe it caused by change of address your proxy server because it cached somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new installation of Windows 8 and the Store tells you that it cannot connect to the Internet (ie. displays the above message - even though other apps can connect) make sure that your date and time are set correctly

If you do not live in the default Windows 8 time zone and so set the time zone during your initial setup of Windows 8 then you must manually set the data and time as well or it will be incorrect, and results in the above problem.

Comment: You're suggesting Windows Store behaves the same way a Windows domain does with respect to time synchronization? Do you have an authoritative reference on that info?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Microsoft store, also creating new MS account for Windows 8 and even with getting developer license for Visual Studio at the same time. It became obvious that problem is related to SSL certificates after I also installed Fiddler (a desktop app for inspecting traffic) and enabled its HTTPS sniffing feature. This can be done with Tools - Fiddler Options - HTTPS - Decrypt HTTPS traffic. FIddler adds fake certificate for every tunnel connection it detects. After that MS Store started to work and also I was able to get developer license. Than I turned off Fiddler, removed fake certificates via certmgr.msc (finding them by "fiddler" keyword), and store was still operating. Somehow this manipulations removed the connection problem, but I can't say if it is some kind of bug, or consequence of hijacking or so...

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer from MS online:

Reset the cache folder in the AppDirectory. To do this, please follow the steps below:

Launch File Explorer, copy and paste the following path in the address bar and hit Enter:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState

Note: replace the text  with the username connected to your account. Also, if your Windows is installed on some other drive, replace C above with the system root drive.

In the LocalState folder, check if the cache folder is showing or not. If it's showing, rename it to cache.old. Once done, create a new folder and name it cache.

Note: In the event that the cache folder is not present by default, just create an empty new folder and name it cache. Close the File Explorer and restart your computer.

After rebooting, run the Windows App troubleshooter again. This should not detect the same error again. Restart your computer once more and try launching the Windows Store.