# Setting system-wide proxy in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy

Is it possible to set a system wide proxy on Windows 10 where all traffic will adhere to? I tried using the LAN settings as well as netsh, but it seems to only affect the browsers and not traffic from other applications.

Comment: If there exist some "system wide proxy" which proxies all traffic (socks-proxy?), you must use some client program (specific for this proxy).

Comment: Yes I'm referring to a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Each socks proxy provides its own client for to install on a client station. Do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. I tried using LAN settings to set, as well as "netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=localhost:8050" bypass-list="localhost" (proxy on port 8050). Neither worked.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible the force every application to use a proxy. You have to use some proxy client or you have to configure it on the network level (forward every traffic to a proxy server on the gateway). https://superuser.com/questions/29701/global-proxy-settings-for-all-windows-applications-in-windows-vista