# Getting Steam.exe to run through a http proxy

Tags: proxy, steam, autoproxy

I'm sitting behind an http proxy which Steam refuses to go through. Trying Proxifier to fix the solution rendered an error about having to use an https proxy, though research shows that it *shouldn't* need one.

Is it possible to make a target parameter in a shortcut?

ie.
    "C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" --http-proxy=myusername:mypassword@SERVERNAME:8080

I have the server name and port number, though I'm yet to understand the relevance of 'myusername:mypassword', or infact which username and password these instructions were referring to.

Of course, if a target parameter wouldn't work, would there be another way to get Steam to work?

Comment: They are referring to your username and password for the proxy, if it requires one.

Answer (score 10):

The Steam client uses UDP by default. Use *-tcp* [launch option](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5623-QOSV-5250) at Steam launch to force the Steam client to only establish TCP connections. This will make the Steam client compatible with the most SOCKS and SSH servers if used in a combination with a proxifier.

Many of the Steam games use UDP and cannot be forced to use TCP instead. Proxifier doesn't support UDP, it will simply ignore UDP traffic. In order to run these games from behind a proxy, you will need an alternative to Proxifier that supports UDP, such as [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com):

> ProxyCap can redirect UDP through a SOCKS5 proxy or a chain of SOCKS5 proxies. The required condition is that UDP relay must be enabled on the proxy server. Also, if you want to run streaming software or online games from behind SOCKS you need to ensure that the connection to the proxy is fast enough.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to get what should have been a very simple SOCKS5 proxy through an SSH tunnel working until I saw this answer. It stinks that this is basically undocumented. By the way, [it works on OS X too](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1266784)!

Comment: this makes the http_proxy env var work on Linux / fedora / ubuntu as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think I tried to achieve this once before, the main issue is whether or not your HTTP proxy supports traversing of UDP, which is unlikely. UDP are necessary for almost any game you might want to play but because it's not used in the HTTP, I don't think you're  going to find your proxy will forward them.

Update to above: **SOCKS proxies can forward UDP traffic and work in reverse: HTTP proxies cannot.**

This is the reason why Steam doesn't make it easy to configure an HTTP proxy. You need to bypass your proxy by opening up port forwards for Steam to get out on. If you don't have control of the proxy server, I'm afraid you're out of luck.