# Is it possible to SSH and tunnel all incoming network trad

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

My college is blocking traffic through certain ports which my applicaton uses (TCP, UDP). When I use a free VPN service like HotSpot VPN. It works fine and redirects all the network traffic through.

Recently, i've got a superuser access on my network through which I can access all the ports as long as I'm using a lab computer. Now, I want to in a way abuse this feature and redirect traffic from my laptop through this superuser access.

I know I can port forward certain ports for HTTP access etc. My question is if I can tunnel all the incoming data *on any port* through the superuser account and into my laptop.

**My Attempt:**

My attempt so far as been to read up various articles :'( I've read that setting up a VPN service on this superuser account and accessing that computer via a SSH tunnel from my Laptop should do the work.

Is that the only or rather the easiest way to go about it? If yes, can you suggest me how I could that.

Comment: "Now, I want to in a way abuse this feature and redirect traffic from my laptop through this superuser access". I'm not sure many people will be comfortable offering you advice on how to abuse your IT privileges.

Comment: Well, the way I put it. It seemed wrong. But it's just that I want to play a few games on steam in my spare time :P

Comment: I have to rush out so haven't read it all, but your second sentence is incomplete. And if your second sentence and third sentence are one sentence, not incomplete, but then what's the problem with a VPN? generally speaking, VPNs are for sending everything through. SSH for just particulars.  I guess you want a VPN.

Comment: It seems like you actually want to redirect outgoing traffic, though?

Comment: @barlop VPN's usually have a very high ping. Almost unplayable. Which is why i wanted to setup some sort of a VPN locally and redirect my traffic through VPN via SSH (if possible)

Comment: @SaikrishnaDeep have you found a local vpn is slow?  or one hosted by others?   if it's a local vpn, then that might not be normal.

Comment: @barlop Nah, I was using a remote VPN. I wanted to setup a VPN locally which is part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a SOCKS proxy via ssh, which is talked about often in the context of Steam specifically; for example:

- [Getting Steam.exe to run through a http proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/387856/getting-steam-exe-to-run-through-a-http-proxy)
- [Force programs that do not specify proxy settings to use a proxy (ie: Steam)](https://superuser.com/questions/18417/force-programs-that-do-not-specify-proxy-settings-to-use-a-proxy-ie-steam)

Note that I'm only answering this since you are unlikely to be deterred by admonishments like MarkoPolo, with whom I agree otherwise. I advise you to use your powers wisely, since you could one day find your powers revoked by those who don't like their networks abused.

Comment: Alright, I think this helps. Will try it out this weekend. The second link was kind of the procedure that I was looking for! :)

Comment: Also make sure, you don't bump into the PermitRootLogin=No restriction of SSH. (I wouldn't recommend changing it.) Eventually setup the firewall appropriately (enable needed ports on INPUT e.g.) You need to setup SSH to listen on additional ports as well.

ssh -D <HIGH PORT NUMBER> or in PuTTY under Connection>SSH>Tunnels the source port can be setup. You need to alter the configuration of you browser as well.

Comment: worth considering though A)What protocols SOCKS supports, i'd guess t doesn't do absolutely any protocol, just a good handful.  And B)The program would have to allow you to specify a proxy for it to use (unless you have some other way to force a program to use a proxy even when it doesn't have the option)