# Proxy Routing Software

Tags: proxy, routing, http-proxy, fiddler, reverse-proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force programs that do not specify proxy settings to use a proxy (ie: Steam)](https://superuser.com/questions/18417/force-programs-that-do-not-specify-proxy-settings-to-use-a-proxy-ie-steam)

I am looking for a software which can route all outgoing/incoming requests through a proxy server rather than via a direction connection to the internet. I have two pieces of software which I cannot use behind a proxy because they do not support proxies.

I would like to avoid tunneling programs, such as WinCap, because they break the honesty policy of my campus network. Instead, I would simply like non-proxied connections to be redirected through the campus proxy.

Can Fiddler do this? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it is a similar question. However, the answer involves SSH tunneling, which, if I were caught using it on this campus, would have severe consequences.

Comment: If you find it's the same question, but don't like the answers try [adding a bounty or alike](http://superuser.com/faq#bounty) to the original question to garner better/different answers.

Comment: What application-layer protocols and ports are those two applications using? HTTP,80 or something else?

Comment: @spryno724: You have interpreted that answer wrong, it says `combined with a SSH tunnel` and it does not say `using a SSH tunnel`.

Comment: My tun2socks software seems to be exactly what you need. It makes a virtual network interface that forwards all incoming connections through SOCKS. http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks

Comment: Why was this closed? It days exact duplicate, without referring to the supposed original.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak it looks like the original poster edited out the duplicate text.

Comment: @spryno724 do not edit out the duplicate text. If you think it was closed incorrectly, you can open a question on [meta] asking for it to be reopened, but just editing it out is not allowed.

Comment: @spryno724 see the Possible Duplicate, where I posted a complete answer using my tun2socks software. http://superuser.com/questions/18417/force-programs-that-do-not-specify-proxy-settings-to-use-a-proxy-ie-steam

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you (or more specifically, the campus) need a [transparent proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy)

Answer (score 0):

[Proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com/) can do this although that it is paid, an alternative free version could be [Proxfier](http://www.proxifier.com/). These are proxy clients that connect applications to proxies, which is what you described. It does not do any tunneling on top of that...

They simple let you specify what applications you want to connect with which proxies.

> Can Fiddler do this? If so, how?

Fiddler is mainly intended to be a HTTP(S) protocol debugger, while you can script things it would be kind of a work-around to need to run Fiddler (which it's overhead) as a proxy client.

Comment: Hmm... is this still tunneling?

Comment: @spryno724: These are clients that connect applications to proxies, which is what you described. It does not do any tunneling on top of that...